# How to solve quadratic inequality with parameters?

Tags: inequality

This is the inequality:
$$n^2-2n-3>M$$
So I just have to solve with the second grade formula but I am stuck:
$n^2-2n-3-M>0$
$\frac{2\pm \sqrt{4-4(-3-M)}}{2}\\
\frac{2\pm \sqrt{16+4M}}{2}$
I don't know how to go on

Comment: I'm sorry but your question isn't clear... You want to solve an inequality in $n$?

Comment: $n^2-2n-3=(n-1)^2-4$ an then $(n-1)^2>M+4$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe yes, sorry i thought it was explicit

Comment: @Fakemistake can you explain why not with the formula?

Comment: No, sorry, it's probably my bad

Comment: "Second grade" ... in English, "quadratic".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For positive $b$, $x^2 > b \implies x \in (-\infty,-\sqrt{b}) \cup (\sqrt{b},\infty)$. For your case, presuming $M \ge -4$, we have
$$n^2-2n+1 > M+4 \\ \implies (n-1)^2 > M+4 \\ \implies (n-1) \in (-\infty,-\sqrt{M+4}) \cup (\sqrt{M+4},\infty) \\ \implies n \in (-\infty,1-\sqrt{M+4}) \cup (1+\sqrt{M+4},\infty).$$
For $M<-4$, $(n-1)^2 \ge 0 > M+4$ is true for all $n\in \mathbb{R}$.

For your approach, the roots of $n^2-2n-3-M=0$ are $1 - \sqrt{M+4} $ and $1 + \sqrt{M+4}$. For $M \ge -4$, we evaluate the given inequality for three intervals: $I_1 = (-\infty,1-\sqrt{M+4})$, $I_2 = (1-\sqrt{M+4},1+\sqrt{M+4})$, and $I_3 = (1+\sqrt{M+4},\infty)$. Afterwards, you evaluate the given inequality for $n \in I_1$, $n \in I_2$ and $n \in I_3$.

For example, if $n \in I_2$ say $n=1$ and $M=5$ then $n^2-2n-3 \color{red}{<} M$. So $n \notin I_2$. Similarly, you can evaluate the other two cases.

Comment: Perfect, the only thing that I don't get is how to use the formula

Comment: Your formula gave you the points $1\pm \sqrt{M+4}$. Can you identify them in the solution posted above?

Comment: If you insist on using the quadratic formula, then you need to evaluate the inequality for three intervals: $(-\infty,1-\sqrt{M+4})$, $(1-\sqrt{M+4},1+\sqrt{M+4})$, and $(1+\sqrt{M+4},\infty)$.

Comment: Can you add to your answer the version with the formula, for some reason I'm a little bit confused and I don't know how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** I assume you want only real-number solutions. First find the solutions (if any) of the corresponding equation 
$$n^2-2n-3-M=0$$ These will partition the number line into 1, 2, or 3 open intervals (since there could be 0, 1, or 2 distinct real roots). On these intervals, the sign of the LHS will be constant (positive or negative). Every point in such an interval where the LHS is positive is a solution to the inequality 
$$n^2-2n-3-M>0$$ which is what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

After you have found

$n=\dfrac{2\pm \sqrt{16+4M}}{2}=1\pm \sqrt{4+M}$

you consider the following possibilities

if $16+4M<0\to M<-4$ then the inequality is verified for any $n$

if $M\ge -4$ then the solution is $n\le1-\sqrt{M+4}\lor n\ge\sqrt{M+4}+1$